# Replace function in Cognos 10 report studio with windchill data source

Tags: replace, cognos

I have a parameter in my report whose values are 
asd,;fgh,; etc . I want to replace " ,; " with " , ". 
I am not able to use Replace function because i am using windchill database.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For parameter you can use macro functions. Something like this:

```
#csv(split(',;',prompt ('p_Parameter' , 'string') ), ',', '')  #
```

Replace p_Parameter with your parameter name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the above solution but I am getting 'Query Specification is incorrect' error.

Comment: Try to change to #csv(split(',;';prompt ('p_Parameter' , 'string') ); ','; '')  # It depends on regional settings. Or, if you use it in conditions add sq. Like #sq(csv(split(',;',prompt ('p_Parameter' , 'string') ), ',', ''))#

Comment: How did you try this? Where? Which part of report? Give full error output

Comment: I added it in the filter and got 'Query Specification is incorrect' error.